# For loop in try except to skip NULL byte

Tags: python, csv, null, try-except

I've got a problem that I can't find a clean solution too. I am reading csv files (~4000 lines each and up to ~2000 files) and some of them contain a NULL byte at random in the file (They shouldn't be there in the first place). They are on their own row and I am trying to find a way to skip them. I feel like the cleanest way to do it would be to put the for loop in a try except and when it hits the NULL byte it will skip to the next iteration of the for loop. My question is if the for loop fails will `continue` move to the next iteration of the loop? I'm assuming it won't but I don't know how to test it easily and I can't think of another way to do this.

Here's some pseudo code for this

```
reader = csv.reader(open('file'))
while 1:
    try:
        for row in reader:
            #do stuff with row
        break
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Maybe you can test with a small data set to see if the behaviour is what you expect? Maybe set up a unit test for this to see how your method behaves with different inputs?

Comment: @idjaw will it continue the for loop or the while loop though?

Comment: If you're trying to remove null bytes from a file, why use csv? Why not just do `infile = open("input.csv"); outfile = open("output.csv", "w"); outfile.write(infile.read().replace("\0", ""))`?

Comment: @Kevin That's not exactly what I want to do but I think I can modify that to work. I'll let you know if it works

Comment: Why do you want to put the for loop in a try except, and not the try except in your for loop instead?

Comment: @DainDwarf because the program errors out when it reads the NULL byte. The error points to the line `for row in reader`

Comment: @Kevin My mind was stuck on using `csv.reader()` but your comment snapped me out of that and it's working now. I just added a replace on the first line of the for loop.

Comment: Did either of my solutions work? If not, what issues are you encountering?

Comment: @Obj3ctiv3_C_88 I didn't try them. I saw Kevin's comment and figured out a solution from there but I don't think they would've worked, or at least not if `csv_file` had been a `csv.reader` object. I don't know why `csv.reader` couldn't handle the NULL byte but once I removed it and just looped over the file normally while stripping the NULL character it worked fine. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: @SirParselot Anytime!

Answer (score 0):

If the null character is on it's own row you should be able to just skip it within a list comprehension. This searches for None but can easily be adjust to search for "" or "Null"

```
csv_as_list = [row for row in csv_file if row is not "\0"]

for row in reader:
    try:
        # do stuff with row
    except:
       continue
```

Comment: I think None and NULL bytes are different things.

Comment: I don't really want to loop over the entire file twice which is what I would have to do with this solution

Comment: Depending on what all you need to do you could just include the logic within the list comprehension, create a partial, or just use a regular for loop. Also, it looks like that will not evaluate anything if it hits an exception. I adjusted my answer to be inline with what you have.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to more easily test what is wrong, you need to isolate the problematic line. Try to count the lines until you reach the exception:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('file'))
parsed_lines = 0
try:
    for row in reader:
        #do stuff with row
        parsed_lines += 1
except:
    print("I had an error on line " + str(parsed_lines))
```

When you can easily test what is wrong, you will probably find a solution more easily.

Comment: I know where the problem is, I'm just not sure how to handle it

Comment: Maybe it could be good to give us some of those problematic lines, so we can fully help.